# Google Analytics 4 does not show the correct revenue.How can I show the correct order amount as total revenue in Google analytics 4 dashboard?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager, revenue

I have added all the required parameter in the datalayer.

[Datalayer Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eValv.png)

Also the total order amount for 3 days is approx 500 but I am getting  240.91 as the total revenue in GA Dashboard. However, I have added coupon for only 3 orders but that also does not amount to 240.91 in any case. So, how can I show the actual amount spent including tax and shipping by the user in the GA4 dashboard.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Please check below screenshots. The Total transaction showing in GA Dashboard: ibb.co/8XLsx7q but the total transaction in admin dashboard for the same duration : ibb.co/4tVnytz GTM Tag : ibb.co/9r8fVbc GTM Trigger: ibb.co/mFZyTCy GTM Tag fired: ibb.co/QYvTzdd GA4 not detected ‘purchase’ event: ibb.co/9NGGph6 Product Array: ibb.co/KwsNZbT GTM variable inside code(gtmGAData): ibb.co/XFVCmhJ DataLayer Push code for thankyou page: ibb.co/rynZr4d

Comment: Also, sometimes the ‘purchase’ event appear in the GA4 test extension but sometimes not like uploaded above so it can be the case that GA4 is not detecting the event properly. @Community